# How can I run IntelliJ IDEA on a remote desktop

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 12 on a remove NX desktop is almost unusable. Screen refreshes are painful as you scroll, and simple operations like selecting text is a chore. Is there any way to improve the experience of IDEA on a remote desktop?

Comment: Also see related IntelliJ bug tracking this - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18341

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This problem has been discussed [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48645). One of the suggestions was to disable double buffering with `RepaintManager.currentManager(null).setDoubleBufferingEnabled(false)`, and set `sun.java2d.noddraw=false` in the **idea.properties** file.

To make things easy, I have created a plugin that toggles double buffering. You can get the source code from [here](https://github.com/mcasperson/IDEADoubleBufferPlugin), or you can download the compiled JAR from [here](https://github.com/mcasperson/IDEADoubleBufferPlugin/blob/master/IDEADoubleBufferPlugin.jar?raw=true).

With the plugin installed, go into the **Tools** menu and select **Enable/Disable Double Buffering**. You will experience a lot of flickering with double buffering disabled, but the performance over a remote desktop connection is significantly improved.

You may also have some luck setting `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true`. See [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18341) for details.

Comment: It works for me as advertised but it does create a lot of flickering in the UI, especially on the right scroll bar. (This was in v13.1)

Comment: This solution probably helped me, but what really made the difference for me was lowering my screen resolution from 1680x1050 to 1400x900. The fact is that  other tools and apps never had the issue even in highest resolution.

Comment: Thanks Phyxx ... the only solution that works (with lots of flickering). Any better solutions by today? I'm having the same issue with Android Studio using IntelliJ.

Comment: Just `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true` solved my problem for a remote with 13ms of RTT.

Comment: The plugin didn't work for me (PyCharm CE 2017.1); nothing showed up in the Tools menu.  But these settings in the **idea.properties** file did the trick: `sun.java2d.noddraw=false` `sun.java2d.d3d=true` `swing.bufferPerWindow=false`.

Comment: I had met this strange behavior when I use vpn to connect my remote desktop ,all these mentioned properties i had tried ,no luck . any more suggestion?

Comment: @Nils & Bart - I've sent a pull request that enables the plugins for all IDEA products (including PyCharm, Android Studio, and CLion) - https://github.com/mcasperson/IDEADoubleBufferPlugin/pull/5

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I tried changing both options: `sun.java2d.noddraw=false` and `sun.java2d.d3d=true` and that made my IDEA much much better!
From [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48645) conversation, seems like the problem is quite common, but the solution varies....

Didn't try the plugin suggested by Phyxx yet, though.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problems (unusably slow, tearing updates while scrolling etc.) running CLion (based on IntelliJ) from a Linux box over an SSH-tunnel to a Mac running XQuartz X11. Adding the `sun.java2d.xrender=true` to the `idea.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try use idea with 2017.2 ,it had used new Windows 10 UI interface, had solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue. I got this fixed by changing the properties on RDP. No parameter added in idea.properties.Please see the pic.put the configuration like that and then connect to RDP.[image: RDP properties]

Comment: That's a lot of settings. Which ones are actually relevant?