# How can i use this suggested intelliJ command to disable double buffering?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use intelliJ 12 - despite requests from ages ago, it still runs *really* slowly on a remote connection.

One of the  suggested settings is to use

`RepaintManager.currentManager(null).setDoubleBufferingEnabled(false);`

I have no idea what that means, but I am keen to try it out - can someone let me know how I can execute this command on my intelliJ? So that it will work smoother, i mean?

Comment: So this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812951/how-can-i-run-intellij-idea-on-a-remote-desktop - doesn't help? Seems like you need to modify idea/idea64.vmoptions to pass the flags mentioned to the JVM and install the plugin the author has created to enable disable double buffering.

Comment: @parry yes, i can edit the jvm flags. However, i kinda wanted to use the java code, and was hoping to find out how to here. Without using the plugin. I'm behind a company firewall, so i cannot get random plugins from the 'net and install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Original issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48645) has [a comment](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-48645#comment=27-418012) that [links to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812951/how-can-i-run-intellij-idea-on-a-remote-desktop) with the [link to plug-in jar](https://github.com/mcasperson/IDEADoubleBufferPlugin/blob/master/IDEADoubleBufferPlugin.jar?raw=true). Download the jar, `Install from disk` in `Setting` | `Plugins`.

Comment: rats. I cannot go around downloading random plugins, which is a shame.

Comment: You can download code from github, review it, put it in a JAR, and then install yourself also if you like. Github repository is https://github.com/mcasperson/IDEADoubleBufferPlugin.